# npm install - Ignore some folders

Tags: npm

When I run `npm install` I find in some installed packages some folders like : `docs`, `samples`, `node_modules` ...

When I was using `bower` I used this :

```
"ignore": [
    "node_modules/**",
    "**/node_modules",
    ".settings/**",
    "src/test/**",
    "target/**",
    "src/main/resources/**",
    "samples/**",
    "docs/**"
  ]
```

How can I do this using npm ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the NPM documentation on `ignore` (https://github.com/npm/cli/wiki/Files-&-Ignores#npmignore), in a file named .npmignore you can set the ignore list:

```
tests/
src/
samples/
```

Just as with bower, you list the files and folders you want to ignore.

Comment: [You probably shouldn't use .npmignore](https://medium.com/@jdxcode/for-the-love-of-god-dont-use-npmignore-f93c08909d8d) because when you use it, it's easy to accidentally publish your credentials.

Answer (score -1):

Create a `.npmignore` and add files to ignore

```
docs/
files_to_ignore/
```

Comment: [You probably shouldn't use .npmignore](https://medium.com/@jdxcode/for-the-love-of-god-dont-use-npmignore-f93c08909d8d) because when you use it, it's easy to accidentally publish your credentials. (I'm not the one that downvoted)